# How to extends props from React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement>?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

"react": "^17.0.2",
"typescript": "^4.2.4"

How to extends props from React.HTMLProps?

```js
import { FC, HTMLProps } from 'react'

export interface SliderButtonProps extends HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement> {
  next?: boolean
}

export const SliderButton: FC<SliderButtonProps> = ({ next = false, ...props }) => {

  return (
    <button  {...props} />
  )
}
```

i get error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix like this:

```
export interface SliderButtonProps extends HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement> {
  next?: boolean;
  type: 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset';
}
```

Or you can use `JSX.IntrinsicElements` like this:

```
type btnType = JSX.IntrinsicElements['button'];
export interface SliderButtonProps extends btnType {
  next?: boolean;
}
```